# migration project from netcore2.2 to netcore3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, sdk, migration

I have a project with Identity Server 4 in netcore2.2
Now I want to migrate to netcore3.0
I have install sdk hosting bundle and so on...
Change version sdk in appsetting change target framework
If I compile tell me ok but...

my old startup.cs have in ConfigureService this call:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build())))
                .AddJsonOptions(options => 
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
                    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                });
```

and netcore 3.0 tell me that options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling
and                          options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling

they are not recognized as valid

so I take out... another problem is that when with debug see the different step the breakpoint inside this call doesn't enter
'

```
services.AddDbContext<DBPLATFORMContext>(options =>
{
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                                                 sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                                                 {
                                                     sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: 5,
                                               maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                                               errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                                                 });
});
```

and when I go to start my indexpage

in Configure
by
'

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                   !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
                   !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
               });
```

variable context give me response 404 and contenttype is null

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET Core 3.0 uses [New JSON serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.1#new-json-serialization), which cause the first issue you mentioned.

Comment: And please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) that explains how to update an existing ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to ASP.NET Core 3.0